# For your complicated algorithms, how do you measure its performance?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, optimization

Let's just assume for now that you have narrowed down where the typical bottlenecks in your app are. For all you know, it might be the batch process you run to reindex your tables; it could be the SQL queries that runs over your effective-dated trees; it could be the XML marshalling of a few hundred composite objects. In other words, you might have something like this:

```
public Result takeAnAnnoyingLongTime(Input in) {
   // impl of above
}
```

Unfortunately, even after you've identified your bottleneck, all you can do is chip away at it. No simple solution is available.

How do you measure the performance of your bottleneck so that you know your fixes are headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

Two points:

1. Beware of the infamous "optimizing the idle loop" problem.  (E.g. see the [optimization story](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/wiki?OptimizationStories) under the heading "Porsche-in-the-parking-lot".)  That is, just because a routine is taking a significant amount of time (as shown by your profiling), don't assume that it's responsible for slow performance as perceived by the user.
2. The biggest performance gains often come not from that clever tweak or optimization to the implementation of the algorithm, but from realising that there's a better algorithm altogether. Some improvements are relatively obvious, while others require more detailed analysis of the algorithms, and possibly a major change to the data structures involved.  This may include trading off processor time for I/O time, in which case you need to make sure that you're not optimizing only one of those measures.

Bringing it back to the question asked, make sure that whatever you're measuring represents what the user actually experiences, otherwise your efforts could be a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Profile it
2. Find the top line in the profiler, attempt to make it faster.
3. Profile it
4. If it worked, go to 1. If it didn't work, go to 2.

Answer (score 2):

I'd measure them using the same tools / methods that allowed me to find them in the first place.

Namely, sticking timing and logging calls all over the place.  If the numbers start going down, then you just might be doing the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [msdn column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500561.aspx), performance tuning is compared to the job of painting Golden Gate Bridge: once you finish painting the entire thing, it's time to go back to the beginning and start again.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a hard problem. The first thing you need to understand is that measuring performance is not how you find performance problems. Knowing how slow something is doesn't help you find out why. You need a diagnostic tool, and a good one. I've had a lot of experience doing this, and [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Optimize-Your-Program%27s-Performance) is the best method. It is not automatic, but it runs rings around most profilers.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question. I don't think anyone knows the answer. I believe that significant part of the problem is that for more complicated programs, no one can predict their complexity. Therefore, even if you have profiler results, it's very complicated to interpret it in terms of changes that should be made to the program, because you have no theoretical basis for what the optimal solution is.

I think this is a reason why we have so bloated software. We optimize only so that quite simple cases would work on our fast machines.  But once you put such pieces together into a large system, or you use order of magnitude larger input, wrong algorithms used (which were until then invisible both theoretically and practically) will start showing their true complexity.

Example: You create a string class, which handles Unicode. You use it somewhere like computer-generated XML processing where it really doesn't matter. But Unicode processing is in there, taking part of the resources. By itself, the string class can be very fast, but call it million times, and the program will be slow.

I believe that most of the current software bloat is of this nature. There is a way to reduce it, but it contradicts OOP. There is an interesting book [There is an interesting book](http://www.cix.co.uk/~smallmemory/book.html) about various techniques, it's memory oriented but most of them could be reverted to get more speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd identify two things:

1) what complexity is it?  The easiest way is to graph time-taken verses size of input.
2) how is it bound?  Is it memory, or disk, or IPC with other processes or machines, or..

Now point (2) is the easier to tackle and explain:  Lots of things go faster if you have more RAM or a faster machine or faster disks or move over to gig ethernet or such.  If you identify your pain, you can put some money into hardware to make it tolerable.